# Kotlin coroutines running sequentially even with keyword async

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Hi guys i'm trying to improve performance of some computation in my system. Basically I want to generate a series of actions based on some data. This doesn't scale well and I want to try doing this in parallel and getting a result after (a bit like how futures work)

I have an interface with a series of implementations that get a collection of actions. And want to call all these in parallel and await the results at the end.

The issue is that, when I view the logs its clearly doing this sequentially and waiting on each action getter before going to the next one. I thought the async would do this asynchronously, but its not.

The method the runBlocking is in, is within a spring transaction. Maybe that has something to do with it.

```kotlin
runBlocking {
       val actions = actionsReportGetters.map { actionReportGetter ->
           async {
             getActions(actionReportGetter, abstractUser)
           }
       }.awaitAll().flatten()

       allActions.addAll(actions)
}
```

```kotlin
private suspend fun getActions(actionReportGetter: ActionReportGetter, traderUser: TraderUser): List<Action> {
        return actionReportGetter.getActions(traderUser)
}
```

```kotlin
interface ActionReportGetter {

    fun getActions(traderUser: TraderUser): List<Action>
}
```

Comment: What logs are you getting? The code looks fine to me. All the async blocks will run in parallel. See [this](https://pl.kotl.in/_L7JkfqpN)

Comment: @ArpitShukla When I remove the code from my implementations of ActionReportGetter and replace it with run blocking and a delay inside of 5 seconds. It runs it all in parallel with with a total of 5 seconds (there are 6 implementations so should be 30 if it was run sequentially). So this works. The only difference is that my implementation query the database using a transaction and this code is not run within a coroutine context in that class. Could it be that coroutine context is only class wide. Sounds weird to say, but thats what it feels like.

Comment: Took 2967 in milis to for <actionImplementation1>

Took 94759 in milis to for <actionImplementation2>

Took 62190 in milis to for <actionImplementation3>

Total = 159966 in milis to get actions for <user>

Comment: What are actionImplementation 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Just implementations of the ActionReportGetter interface. I omitted the real names

Comment: Btw i forgot to ask, are you using `runBlocking` in your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are doing some blocking operation in `ActionReportGetter.getActions` in a single threaded environment (probably in the main thread).
For such IO operations you should launch your coroutines in `Dispatchers.IO` which provides a thread pool with multiple threads.

Update your code to this:

```kotlin
async(Dispatchers.IO) { // Switch to IO dispatcher
    getActions(actionReportGetter, abstractUser
}
```

Also `getActions` need not be a suspending function here. You can remove the `suspend` modifier from it.

Comment: I think this has worked. I will do some more testing and let you know

Comment: It worked, ive awarded this post. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)